# my div is overflowing though i applied overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

Please i have tried to look for solutions to this div but found none, I dont want my div to overflow and create a scroll. How can i adjust it that it wont overflow again.Thanks. My code is below

```css
.contact-bar {
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
.contact-top {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 5px;
}
.contact-top p {
    margin: 0 20px;
    color: white;
}
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row contact-bar">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 contact-top">
        <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span> </span><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>  +2347033501657</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 contact-top">
        <p><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> allamit@gmail.com</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: simply follow bootstrap rules :ROW inside CONTAINER

Comment: @TemaniAfif it worked fine. i am sorry i am a bad reader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap `row` in a `container` or `container-fluid` as per your requirements

```css
.contact-bar {
 /*overflow: hidden;*/
 
}
.contact-top {
 background-color: #1a1a1a;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 padding: 5px;

}
.contact-top p {
 margin: 0 20px;
 color: white;

}
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row contact-bar">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 contact-top">
        <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span> </span><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>  +2347033501657</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 contact-top">
        <p><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> allamit@gmail.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a8sc2wsu/)

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider upvote. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the row and use the container. Hope it helps..

```css
.contact-bar {
 /*overflow: hidden;*/
 
}
.contact-top {
 background-color: #1a1a1a;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 padding: 5px;

}
.contact-top p {
 margin: 0 20px;
 color: white;

}
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <div class="container contact-bar">
  
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 contact-top">
   <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span> </span><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>  +2347033501657</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 contact-top">
   <p><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> allamit@gmail.com</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`overflow:hidden;` applies hide to its childrens. But in this case it is you `contact-bar`class that wraps them all. So you need to apply overflow:hidden to the one that contains `contact-bar` which is `body`. By the way, you bootstrap applies `-15px margin` and thats why there is a gap in the example code of mine.

[**https://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=e42b821765c82cdc32e457c79b638d35**](https://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=e42b821765c82cdc32e457c79b638d35)